# pandas plot a specific column to be used as both x and y axis?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe that looks like the below:

I want to `plot company_id` as the x axis and `count(company_id)` for the y axis.
I also want to stack it by category of `open` and `close`.

The code doesnt show any output and runs infinitely.

```
df
        person_id  company_id   time    event   type    date
    0          1    255      1379312026 open    A   2013-09-16 02:13:46
    1          1    255      1379312086 close   A   2013-09-16 02:14:46
    2          1    182      1379312926 open    B   2013-09-16 02:28:46
    3          1    182      1379313046 close   B   2013-09-16 02:30:46
    4          1    81       1379314006 open    A   2013-09-16 02:46:46


df2=df[['company_id','event']]
df2.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

Comment: Would recommend Seaborn for this. They have methods that do small computations on the fly while plotting. Take a look at this Seaborn example plots page: https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to use `seaborn` as suggested in a comment you could do this:

```
import seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = {'company_id': {0: 255, 1: 255, 2: 182, 3: 182, 4: 81}, 
      'time': {0: 1379312026, 1: 1379312086, 2: 1379312926, 3: 1379313046, 4: 1379314006}, 
      'person_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}, 
      'counts': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1}, 
      'type': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'A'}, 
      'event': {0: 'open', 1: 'close', 2: 'open', 3: 'close', 4: 'open'}}

# add counts column    
counts = df.groupby('company_id').size().rename('counts')
df['count'] = df['company_id'].map(counts)

g = sns.factorplot(y='count',x='company_id',hue='event',data=df,kind='bar',
                   palette='muted',legend=False,ci=None)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]